# ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here on Python

Tags: python, yaml

I am having some problems about opening a yaml file I should work with for a group project.

The code that gives the error is pretty simple;

```
import yaml
with open('test2.yaml') as f:    
    data = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    print(data)
```

And the error message is;

```
ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "test2.yaml", line 118, column 73
```

I have looked into the problem and it was supposed to be a problem with the format of the yaml file. However, I tried this with diferent yaml files and none of them work. I also tried an online yaml file validator and the files seem just fine. I really don't understand what is wrong here and would appreciate any help deeply.

By the way, a sample of the yaml file also looks like the following;

```
description:
  set: 'Container'
  name: 'Test'
layout:
  containers:
  - id: 1
    kindid: 1
    loadingspaces:
    - id: 1
      placements:
      - id: 1
        itemid: 1
        position: 0,0,0
        orientation: 'LWH'
      - id: 2
        itemid: 1
        position: 0,0,500
        orientation: 'LWH'
      - id: 3
        itemid: 1
        position: 0,500,0
        orientation: 'LWH'
  pallets: []
  boxes: []
  unplaced:
  - id: 4
    itemid: 1
    quantity: 1
```

Comment: I think the error lies in your YAML file... it isn't formatted as it should be. Could you try one more time with just the sample that you've posted... it works fine with me

Comment: I agree with @Anwarvic, your sample loads just fine. See [demo](https://repl.it/repls/JealousVirtuousBaitware). Post a sample YAML that fails to load.